# Telerik Radgrid row delete and restore the data on adding new row dynamically

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I've the below code working just to display the radgrid headers with a button "Add new Course". Initially on page load I have no data to bind to radgrid. On "Add new Course" button click I add a new row to the RadGrid with 2 textboxes and 2 dropdownlist(binded from db). Each row should have "remove row' button. I've these working. Now my issue is I need to restore the data that has been entered by user when the user is trying to add another new row to the grid. And also how do I remove the row? Kindly help me by your suggestions or hightlight me the mistake in my existing code. thanks in advance.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" MasterTableView-CommandItemSettings-ShowAddNewRecordButton="false"  MasterTableView-CommandItemSettings-ShowRefreshButton="false" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
        OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand">
        <MasterTableView Width="100%" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" CommandItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" DataKeyNames="IsAdd,BusID" CommandItemDisplay="Top" CommandItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
            <CommandItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="IsAdd" Font-Size="Small" Font-Bold="true" CommandName="InitInsert" Text ="Add New Bus" runat="server" />
            </CommandItemTemplate>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="BusID" HeaderText="Bus #" DataField="BusID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Name"  HeaderText="Bus Series" DataField="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="SeriesDropDown" DataTextField="SeriesName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Bus Group" DataField="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="GroupDropDown" DataTextField="GroupName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>               
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="VIN" DataField="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Remove Row" CommandName="Delete" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

            </Columns>              

        </MasterTableView>         
    </telerik:RadGrid>  
    <asp:Button ID="savebtn" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="Save Rows"/>
```

aspx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("BusID");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("IsAdd");

            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Name1", false);
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Name2", false);
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Name3", false);

            Session["dt"] = dt;
        }
    }

    protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGrid1.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
    }
    protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();           

        if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
        {
            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            TextBox TextBox1 = item.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
            Button Button1 = item.FindControl("Button1") as Button;                

            DropDownList SeriesDropDown = item.FindControl("SeriesDropDown") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList GroupDropDown = item.FindControl("GroupDropDown") as DropDownList;
            TextBox TextBox4 = item.FindControl("TextBox4") as TextBox;

            DataSet busGroup_Dataset = admin.GetBusGroup();
            GroupDropDown.DataSource = busGroup_Dataset;
            GroupDropDown.DataBind();

            DataSet busSeries_Dataset = admin.GetBusSeries();
            SeriesDropDown.DataSource = busSeries_Dataset;
            SeriesDropDown.DataBind();


            bool isAdd = Convert.ToBoolean(item.GetDataKeyValue("IsAdd"));
            if (isAdd)
            {
                TextBox1.Visible = SeriesDropDown.Visible = GroupDropDown.Visible = TextBox4.Visible = true;
                btn.Visible = true;
                RadGrid1.DataSource = Session["dt"];
            }
            else
            {
                TextBox1.Visible = SeriesDropDown.Visible = GroupDropDown.Visible = TextBox4.Visible = false;
                Button1.Visible = false;                   
            }
        }

    }


    protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.InitInsertCommandName)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
            dt.Rows.Add(0, string.Empty, true);
            RadGrid1.MasterTableView.IsItemInserted = false;
            e.Canceled = true;
            RadGrid1.Rebind();
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {

            string ID = e.Item.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[e.Item.ItemIndex]["0"].ToString();
            DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
            if (table.Rows.Find(ID) != null)
            {
                table.Rows.Find(ID).Delete();
                table.AcceptChanges();
                Session["dt"] = table;
            }


            RadGrid1.Rebind();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Telerik RadGrid provides rich server API for inserting new data,
>   updating existing data and deleting data.

As telerik admin told you on official forum read the doc as i told you to do so 8 day earlier.

#### See the magic in action in the demo , learn more about it in the doc :

- Please look at the [telerik asp demo about DATA EDITING](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/automatic-crud-operations/defaultcs.aspx).
- [There is so mutch information about Data Editing](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/data-editing/edit-mode/batch-editing/server-side-api)

## Let me do it for you !

> The following exemple where developped in a new/clean telerik project you can just copy past them to try.

### 1/. With Advance binding Aka onNeedDataSource

In ASPX :

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1"runat="server"
                     OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" 
                     GroupingEnabled="False" 
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                     OnInsertCommand="RadGrid1_InsertCommand" 
                     AllowSorting="True" 
                     AllowPaging="True">
    <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" EditMode="Batch" >
        <CommandItemSettings ShowExportToPdfButton="false" ShowExportToExcelButton="false"  ShowPrintButton="false" />
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CourseID" HeaderText="CourseID" DataField="CourseID" DataType="System.Int32" >
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="CourseNumber" HeaderText="CourseNumber" DataField="CourseNumber" DataType="System.Int32">
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Location" HeaderText="Location" DataField="Location" DataType="System.String" >
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" DataType="System.String" >
            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

In CodeBehind :

```
    public ObjectContainer myDatasource
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["test_01"] == null)
            Session["test_01"] = new ObjectContainer();

        return Session["test_01"] as ObjectContainer ;
    }
    set { Session["test_01"] = value; }
}

protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    YoData row = new YoData();
    ObjectContainer tempo = new ObjectContainer();
    GridBatchEditingEventArgument argument = e.CommandArgument as GridBatchEditingEventArgument;
    Hashtable newValues = argument.NewValues;

    row.CourseID = Int32.Parse(newValues["CourseID"].ToString());
    row.CourseNumber = Int32.Parse(newValues["CourseNumber"].ToString());
    row.Location = newValues["Location"].ToString();
    row.Name = newValues["Name"].ToString();

    myDatasource.YoDatas.Add(row);
}

protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    if ( ! IsPostBack )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            YoData row = new YoData();
            row.CourseID = i + 1;
            row.CourseNumber = i + 1;
            row.Name = "Name " + (i + 1);
            row.Location = "Country " + (i + 1);

            myDatasource.YoDatas.Add(row);
        }
    } 
    RadGrid1.DataSource = myDatasource.YoDatas;
}
```

In App_Code:

> Im using object instead of DataTable, because it's easier.

```
namespace Demo
{
public class ObjectContainer
{
    public ObservableCollection<YoData> YoDatas;


    public ObjectContainer()
    {
        YoDatas = new ObservableCollection<YoData>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<YoData> get_yoda(int mode = 0)
    {
        return this.YoDatas;
    }
    public void set_yoda(int CourseID, int CourseNumber, string Location, string Name)
    {
        YoData _temp = new YoData(CourseID, CourseNumber, Location, Name);
        this.YoDatas.Add(_temp);
    }

}
public class YoData
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int CourseNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime CourseDate { get; set; }
    public String Location { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }



    public YoData()
    {
        CourseID = 0;
        CourseNumber = 0;
        CourseDate = DateTime.Now;
        Location = "";
        Name = "";
    }

    public YoData(int a, int b, DateTime c, string d, string e)
    {
        CourseID = a;
        CourseNumber = b;
        CourseDate = c;
        Location = d;
        Name = e;
    }
    public YoData(int a, int b, string d, string e)
    {
        CourseID = a;
        CourseNumber = b;
        CourseDate = DateTime.Now;
        Location = d;
        Name = e;
    }
}
}
```

### 2/. in automatics, telerik do it for ya ( Later )

[edit comming soon....]

This is not the best solution, there must be some mistake in the code but it works. This is done with only the doc.

I hope this helps, 
Regards,
Pierre.

Comment: is it really possible to add a new row on button click and when the user enters new data to the new row(not saved yet), maintain the data entered when the user tries to add another new row(postback happens here) to the radgrid. Finally after the user had added required rows, hits save where all the row data gets saved to the database. Kindly advice. I've reached to a point where i can add rows on button click but doesn't maintain the data on postback.

Comment: Try View state / session to store data .. then save to db when you want

Comment: @BVidhya, I saw your post on official forum still need help for this ?